# Can I provide multiple Accessibility IDs to a single UI element?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation

I was wondering whether I could provide multiple accessibility ids to a single UI element.

Also, if the above scenario is possible, then would I be able to summon the same UI element by all its accessibility ids?

Answer (score 0):

The ID attribute is the element identity by it's definition.
So, if a web element has some ID it should be unique. Otherwise it's not ID!
So, technically, maybe, it's possible, but this conflicts with the basic definition of the ID attribute.